# VSCode Vim -- don't want escape to enter normal mode if I'm exiting tooltip or Intellisense

Tags: normal-mode, vscode

I'm new to VIM and I'm loving it. I'm learning slowly but surely. I've passed the point where there's enough benefit and not too much hassle. I'm using the VS code integration. I'm learning VIM (slowly) AND learning how to integrate VIM with VS Code successfully and with minimal collisions. So far so good.

There's one little collision that happens. When I hit exit I enter normal mode. Escape is my main goto to enter normal mode. I don't want to change that or use ctrl (right now at least) as I rely on that for other commands. I just don't want it to enter normal mode while I'm trying to exit a tooltip or IntelliSense auto complete.

Any way?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! A note to others: remember that VS Code's vim plugin is [help/on-topic]. OP, can you clarify "hit exit" or "exiting tooltip or Intellisense"? I don't use VS Code, but it's hard for me to understand what you mean—are you pressing Escape, or clicking a GUI element (like the little `[x]`) or something else?

Comment: To me it looks like an issue with the VS code plugin not replicating Vi/Vim/Neovim behavior which makes it off topic

Comment: Oops didn't realize it was OT. What I mean @D.BenKnoble is I'll be typing a method or variable and it will give me an auto-complete suggestion from a list. I can hit tab and it will complete what it suggests for me. If I don't want that, I hit escape to exit the pop up but escape also exits insert mode. It does two things at once. I only want the button to do one thing at once.

Comment: Yeah, that might be OT, not sure. But it would probably get further as a bug report with the vscode extension devs for the vim extension

Comment: You can use `Shift-Esc` to dismiss the unhelpful Intellisense window. Using `Shift-Esc` instead of `Esc` avoids the transition to Normal mode. From [here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1360#issuecomment-298580000)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and started using Shift Esc for closing VSCode suggestions without leaving insert mode.

Not sure if I had to set up any mapping on keybindings.json, though.